Skipping loading plugin due to problem with signature
I want to add Oracle Enterprise Manager App plugin to my existing Grafana server. I have successfully completed all the steps on the Oracle document but I cannot see Oracle Enterprise Manager App on the Grafana plugins page. I am getting the following error in Grafana logs
logger=plugins.signature.validation t=2024-09-20T00:43:27.024398121+03:00 level=warn msg=“Skipping loading plugin due to problem with signature” pluginId=oracle-emcc-app status=unsigned
logger=plugins.validation t=2024-09-20T00:43:27.024423916+03:00 level=error msg=“Plugin validation failed” pluginId=oracle-emcc-app error=“plugin ‘oracle-emcc-app’ has no signature”
logger=plugins.signature.validation t=2024-09-20T00:43:27.024440438+03:00 level=warn msg=“Skipping loading plugin due to problem with signature” pluginId=oracle-emcc-datasource status=unsigned
logger=plugins.validation t=2024-09-20T00:43:27.024448276+03:00 level=error msg=“Plugin validation failed” pluginId=oracle-emcc-datasource error=“plugin ‘oracle-emcc-datasource’ has no signature”
I added oracle-emcc-app, oracle-emcc-datasource to the allow_loading_unsigned_plugins parameter to solve the error but it did not work. Can you help?

Make sure you are using right plugin version with right certified Grafana version. I guess you are using newer version, where it works differently and plugin is not prepared for that.
Doc: https://www.oracle.com/enterprise-manager/technologies/grafana/

Actually, I downloaded oem plugin version 3.0 and it is supported 8.2.7 . I use grafana server version 11 so.. I guess it is right combinations.

@MaybeExpertDBA See doc, plugin 3.0 is certified with Grafana server 8.2.7, not with 11. You are running not certified setup, so you can expect problems - that's exactly what you see.
